# Best way to preserve config file between git pulls

Tags: git

It is really anoying to recreate a config file after every `git pull`. Is there a good method to keep a file from being overwritten, or better yet, only if the remote config file has changed?

Comment: "Recreate a config file after every git pull" - what do you mean?  Are you locally editing a tracked file?

Comment: Yes, the default config is in the repo, but after git pull it is reset to default.

Comment: Please read [how to write a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always try to store config files out of the repo.  So I usually have a `config.xml.example` or `_config.xml` (some filename that isn't actually used) and include the real `config.xml` in your `.gitignore` file.  Once you clone the repository, copy and paste the file and update the configuration settings.  You can also store production config files in a special directory on your server, and always copy this file over when deploying a build (that way you always know your configuration file will be the right data).  This also lets you store passwords outside of a repository for security.

Comment: I hadn't thought of this, this seems like the best way.